# Problem (semi-newb) about async - await. Everything seems correct, works on other Task, but not on another

Tags: c#

I have a method where i get the await error:
Error   12  The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.    c:\abemscan_marq\form1.cs   1480    13  AbemisMicro

It works fine on one method, but not on the other. Even when I delete everything from the method (except a simple, int debugflag = 1;). Error does not go away.

I can't understand it. VS 2013 fyi.

I've attached code below and a screenshot of the code just fyi. 
Any help greatly appreciated!
I have to be able to solve this simple problem.

[image: Screen shot]

NOTE that the error stays there, even if I delete everything in the method, so I don't think the Process call or other is making this happen.

```
        private void btnMRFA_rminus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int ncpos = int.Parse(txtMRFA_cpos.Text);
            int nsteps = int.Parse(txtMRFA_steps.Text);
            Application.DoEvents();
            //note the negative
            await MRFA_move(-nsteps);

        }
        private async Task MRFA_move(int nsteps)
        {
            Process myProcess = new Process();
            string scmd;
            int ncpos = int.Parse(txtMRFA_cpos.Text);
            double ncalib = double.Parse(txtMRFA_calib.Text);
            double ncdeg = double.Parse(txtMRFA_cdeg.Text);

            int dbgtest = nsteps; //just dbg
            //setting position to be absolute position of motor, not as indicated in the manual (ambiguous)
            int movepos = ncpos + nsteps;
            scmd = "--resume --position " + movepos.ToString();
            try
            {
                myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                // You can start any process, HelloWorld is a do-nothing example.
                myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "ticcmd";
                myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = scmd;
                myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                myProcess.Start();
                //with async, it's possible that this delay is not necessary. keep it in for now.
                int movetime = (int)((double)(Math.Abs(ncpos - nsteps) * 2500) / 100 + 100) ;
                //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(movetime);
                await putdelay(movetime);
                // This code assumes the process you are starting will terminate itself. 
            }
            catch
            {
                string catcherr = "something went wrong";
            }

            scmd = "--deenergize";
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            // You can start any process
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "ticcmd";
            myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = scmd;
            myProcess.Start();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            int updpos = ncpos + nsteps;
            txtMRFA_cpos.Text = updpos.ToString();
            ncdeg = (double)updpos / ncalib;
            txtMRFA_cdeg.Text = ncdeg.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: `await MRFA_move(-nsteps);`: you cannot await in a non async method. Make the handler `async`. That `Application.DoEvents();` should vanish.

Comment: I figured it out. THANKS. The problem was I had to async the originating _Click method. App doevents was removed.

Comment: Update, still not working. well it sort of worked. now it hangs sometimes, but not other times.. sheesh.

Comment: Your `MRFA_move` method is not exactly an async-able one. You also use `Thread.Sleep();` inside (blocking). You should use `await Task.Delay()` instead. But it's not even the point, here. You're just starting a couple of processes. You could use the asynchronous version (event-driven): set `EnableRaisingEvents = true`, subscribe to the `Exited` event and let the process terminate then evaluate the result in the Exited handler, if needed. Or you could use `Task.Run()` to start a couple of Tasks. So, in my opinion, the whole procedure needs to be rewritten from the ground up.

Comment: Thanks again. I agree am rewriting. The main problem, along with your comments, is that I'm trying to run another process (ticcmd.exe) which i guess doesn't work with using async. I think something along the lines of Jimi's comment is possibly a way forward, but it might be impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Make the button click method async (second word in the code sample) too.

```
private async void btnMRFA_rminus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
      int ncpos = int.Parse(txtMRFA_cpos.Text);
     int nsteps = int.Parse(txtMRFA_steps.Text);
     Application.DoEvents(); 
    //note the negative 
     await MRFA_move(-nsteps); 
 }
```